# Jira REST API - Fetch all users data from a resource

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to fetch a resource of All users list in Jira,
but Jira API sends list of only 50 users.
I want to fetch list of all users.
How can I do it?

**endpoint:**
https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/users/search

Response (only 50 users, not all users)

```
[
    {
        "self": "https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=*********************",
        "accountId": "*********************",
        "accountType": "customer",
        "displayName": "Former user",
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "self": "https://myurl.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/user?accountId=************************",
        "accountId": "************************",
        "accountType": "atlassian",
        "emailAddress": "****************",
        "displayName": "*************",
        "active": true,
        "locale": "en_US"
    },
    {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add in the query the param:

```
startAt=0&maxResults=1000
```

Comment: Thank you, its working, any way to know total number of items and dynamically fetch till last item without hardcoding maxResults.
I want maxResults to be dynamically passed in query